# Problem related to dimensional analysis

Tags: dimensional-analysis

In dimensional analysis, why is $\pi$ not considered a base quantity (length)? Why is it considered a magnitude?

Comment: $\pi$ as in [Buckingham π theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckingham_%CF%80_theorem), or $\pi$ as in 3.14159265359..?

Comment: -1 Why do you think it should be a length?

Comment: @sammygerbil, guess to do with circle perhaps, but I agree ---

Comment: @jimgao  the point is $\pi$ is defined (I guess) as the ratio of circumfrence divided by diameter of a circle, so it is length/length and should be dimensionless

Comment: This question is like asking why is $a$ not a length scale; it can be but only if you defined as such. Letters (even greek ones like $\pi$) are just used as a representation of physical quantity in physics. They only have meaning if you give it to them and are consistent. You want $\pi$ to be a length scale? That ok (although will be confusing most people), but then don't use it as the ratio of the circumference to diameter of a circle because that's inconsistent.

Comment: @sammygerbil please... I know that this was the dumbest question asked on stackexchange

Comment: @tom i have something like autism. I was confused...

Comment: @Jimgao - no problem at all - in fact, to be honest it is an important question to ask, and it is necessary to know that $\pi$ is dimensionless. I hope this does not discourage you from asking other questions on Physics Stackexcahnge

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\pi={c \over d}$ where $c$ is the circumference and $d$ is the diameter. The unit of measurement of both $c$ and $d$ is a unit of length, thus they cancel out. That's why $\pi$ is dimensionless.

Answer (score 5):

The number $\pi$ is a ratio. For example the circumference of a circle is:

$$ C = 2\pi r $$

so:

$$ \pi = \frac{C}{2r} $$

or likewise using the area of a circle, $A$, we get:

$$ \pi = \frac{A}{r^2} $$

If you look at the dimensional quantities in these equations you'll find that $\pi$ has no dimensions.

Comment: Oh Yes! It's the ratio of two lengths and they cancel out, so pi is dimension less. Thank you! I just realised how wrong I was